# Custom attribute binding in HTML

Tags: angular

Using Angular 5, I bind data-target as `[attr.data-target]="id"`

JavaScript Object

```
var ids = [1, 2];
```

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let id in ids">
    <p [attr.data-target]="id"></p>
</div>
```

which gets rendered as

```
<div>
    <p data-target="1"></p>
    <p data-target="2"></p>
</div>
```

The aim is achieve something like

```
<div>
    <p data-target="collapse1"></p>
    <p data-target="collapse2"></p>
</div>
```

How to prepend/append some static `string` to attributes (date-*, aria*)?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this:

**Interpolation**

```html
attr.data-target="collapse{{id}}"
```

**Attribute binding**

```html
[attr.data-target]="'collapse' + id"
```

**Attribute binding canonical form**

```html
bind-attr.data-target="'collapse' + id"
```

**Using custom method**

**ts**

```html
getTarget(id) {
  return `collapse${id}`;
}
```

**html**

```html
[attr.data-target]="getTarget(id)"
```

or

```html
bind-attr.data-target="getTarget(id)"
```

Live example on **[ng-run](https://ng-run.com/edit/XZPCCNvVeoUdVUAcPJeE)**

Answer (score 3):

It works the same way you append with two way binding variable, in this case

```
<p [attr.data-target]="'collapse' + id">
```